# Flag as duplicate option is ... duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

It just came to my attention that when flagging (not VTC) a Question as duplicate one is presented with the following options:

[image]

As we can see, among those is the *"a duplicate..."* option. However, if we select the *"should be closed..."* option instead, we are presented *again* with an option to flag as duplicate:

[image]

---

**I wonder what is the reason for the redundancy in that specific option?** Are users more prone to select *"should be closed..."* instead and thus justify including the option there as well?

Comment: If this question has been asked before - Meta might explode. ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek duplicate overflow.

Comment: .... You sir, might have doomed us all.. Maybe duped us all. Jury's out on that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard still the question remains unanswered: what is the reason? Is a shortcut or power feautre as you commented there? Or perhaps most close reasons are dupes and thus the need for that link..

Comment: I plan to write my own answer there soon, and yeah, having lots of duplicates is most likely one of the main reasons. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Already read it :) interestingly that was a 5 year old question

Comment: Age isn't relevant for questions here, be it bug reports, feature requests, or discussions. :)